# Including logging as part of my domain model

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, error-logging

I'm writing an application where logging is part of my actual domain model. It's an automation and batch processing tool where end users will be able to view the logs of a batch processing job in the actual application and not just text log files.

So my domain model includes a `LogMessage` class:

```
public sealed class LogMessage
{
    public string Message { get; }
    public DateTime TimestampUtc { get; }
    public LogLevel Level { get; }
}

public enum LogLevel
{
    Fatal = 5,
    Error = 4,
    Warn = 3,
    Info = 2,
    Debug = 1,
    Trace = 0
}
```

I also have a `Result` class which has a collection property of `LogMessages`. Results can be saved to and opened from files with my application by end users.

```
public class Result
{
    public bool Succeeded {get; set;}
    public string StatusMessage {get; set;}
    public IList<LogMessage> LogMessages {get; set;}
}
```

My application also supports third party developers extending the application with plug-ins that can also write log messages. So I've defined a generic `ILogger` interface for the plug-in developers.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Debug(string message);
    void Error(string message);
    void Fatal(string message);
    void Info(string message);
    void Log(LogLevel level, string message);
    void Trace(string message);
    void Warn(string message);
}
```

I provide an instance of an `ILogger` to the plug-ins which writes to `Result.LogMessages`.

```
public interface IPlugIn
{
    Output DoSomeThing(Input in, ILogger logger);
}
```

I obviously also want to be able to log from my own internal code and ultimately want `Result.LogMessages` to contain a mixture of my internal log messages and log messages from plug-ins. So an end user having trouble could send me a Result file that would contain debug logs both from my internal code, and any plug-ins used.

Currently, I have a solution working using a custom NLog target.

```
public class LogResultTarget : NLog.Targets.Target
{
    public static Result CurrentTargetResult { get; set; }

    protected override void Write(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        if (CurrentTargetResult != null)
        {
            //Convert NLog logEvent to LogMessage
            LogLevel level = (LogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogLevel), logEvent.Level.Name);
            LogMessage lm = new LogMessage(logEvent.TimeStamp.ToUniversalTime(), level, logEvent.Message);
            CurrentTargetResult.LogMessages.Add(lm);
        }
    }

    protected override void Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        Write(logEvent.LogEvent);
    }
}
```

This class forwards message to the `Result` assigned to the static `LogResultTarget.CurrentTargetResult` property. My internal code logs to NLog loggers, and and I have a implementation of `ILogger` that logs to an `NLog.Logger` as well.

This is working, but feels really fragile. If `CurrentTargetResult` is not set correctly or not set back to null I can end up with log messages being stored to results that they do not apply to. Also because there is only one static `CurrentTargetResult` there's no way I could support processing multiple results simultaneously.

Is there a different/better way I could approach this? Or is what I'm trying to do fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I don't fully understand the `CurrentTargetResult` property, it's not used in your current target? (Only null check?) How exactly looks the `Result` type looks like?

Comment: Ah looks like I had a typo in my example code where I had "Target" instead of "CurrentTargetResult". I also added an example of the "Result" class. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, added an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is the right one, but you could save effort by using a library which already does this abstraction for you. The [Common Logging](https://net-commons.github.io/common-logging/) library is what you're after.

Your domain code will depend only on the `ILogger` interface from Common Logging. Only when your domain is used by a runtime e.g. Web API, do you then configure what logging provider you're going to use.

There are a number of pre-built providers available as separate nuget packages:

Common.Logging provides adapters that support all of the following popular logging targets/frameworks in .NET:

- Log4Net (v1.2.9 - v1.2.15)
- NLog (v1.0 - v4.4.1)
- SeriLog (v1.5.14)
- Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging Application Block (v3.1 - v6.0)
- Microsoft AppInsights (2.4.0)
- Microsoft Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)
- Log to STDOUT
- Log to DEBUG OUT

I've used this for a number of years and it's been great to have your domain/library code be reused in another context, but not have to have a fixed dependency on a logging framework (I've moved from Enterprise Libraries to log4net, to finally NLog ... it was a breeze).

Answer (score 0):

In think the `static` CurrentTargetResult  is indeed a bit fragile, but the overal approach is fine.

I propose the following changes:

1. unstatic the `CurrentTargetResult`, and always make it initialized,

   Something like this:

   ```cs
   public class LogResultTarget : NLog.Targets.Target
   {
       public Result CurrentTargetResult { get; } = new Result();

       protected override void Write(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
       {
           //Convert NLog logEvent to LogMessage
           LogLevel level = (LogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogLevel), logEvent.Level.Name);
           LogMessage lm = new LogMessage(logEvent.TimeStamp.ToUniversalTime(), level, logEvent.Message);
           CurrentTargetResult.LogMessages.Add(lm);
       }

       protected override void Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
       {
           Write(logEvent.LogEvent);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Always initialize the LogMessages:

   ```cs
   public class Result
   {
       public bool Succeeded {get; set;}
       public string StatusMessage {get; set;}
       public IList<LogMessage> LogMessages {get; set;} = new List<LogMessage>();
   }
   ```
3. Retrieve the messages - when needed - with the following calls:

   ```cs
   // find target by name
   var logResultTarget1 = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<LogResultTarget>("target1");
   var results = logResultTarget1.CurrentTargetResult;

   // or multiple targets
   var logResultTargets = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.OfType<LogResultTarget>();
   var allResults = logResultTargets.Select(t => t.CurrentTargetResult);
   ```

PS: You could also overwrite `InitializeTarget` in `LogResultTarget` for initialing the target